# Android: How to use MTK 6575 to debugg my android application

Tags: android, android-emulator

I have **MTK 6575 N8000 Android 4.0.3** mobile phone and I want to run my application which is developed in Eclipse. But when I try to run my application then Eclipse not detect this device.
So can any one suggest me what the thing I need to set or download to run my application on this device.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
To install the Android USB driver on Windows XP for the first time:

Connect your Android-powered device to your computer's USB port. Windows will detect the device and launch the Hardware Update Wizard.
Select Install from a list or specific location and click Next.
Select Search for the best driver in these locations; un-check Search removable media; and check Include this location in the search.
Click Browse and locate the USB driver folder. (The Google USB Driver is located in <sdk>\extras\google\usb_driver\.)
Click Next to install the driver.
Or, to upgrade an existing Android USB driver on Windows XP with the new driver:

Connect your Android-powered device to your computer's USB port.
Right-click on My Computer from your desktop or Windows Explorer, and select Manage.
Select Device Manager in the left pane.
Locate and expand Android Phone in the right pane.
Right-click Android Composite ADB Interface and select Update Driver. This will launch the Hardware Update Wizard.
Select Install from a list or specific location and click Next.
Select Search for the best driver in these locations; un-check Search removable media; and check Include this location in the search.
Click Browse and locate the USB driver folder. (The Google USB Driver is located in <sdk>\extras\google\usb_driver\.)
Click Next to upgrade the driver.
```

Answer (score 1):

Install Google usb Driver or else Select the Run Configuration Choose Manual for Compiling the Program on your Device

Comment: eclipse not detecting the device then how I choose manual ...

Comment: whether ur usb is detected in system

Comment: when I connect mobile to the system then it detect device storage driver I am able to open but when I go to device manager then it showing MT65XX Android phone in other device section and when I click on property then it show The drivers for this device are not installed

Answer (score 1):

Go to my Computer icon
Right Click on my Computer icon  and Select Manage

Select Device Manager

and Choose Usb Port

Un Plug and Plugin ur Usb Device

Then Select ur Usb Port .....

Give Update Driver 
and Browse For the Folder

Androis SDK in your computer and Select Google Usb Folder and Select OK .....

it will install a driver which support all usb drivers ...... 
try it man

Comment: thanx dear it work in my Window 7 computer but I am till struggling in window xp computer.